# How can I sandbox a third-party library within my Android application?

Tags: android, android-permissions, sandbox

I include an AAR in my app which comes from a third party.  My app declares lots of permissions, and has access to APIs that could potentially be used to access sensitive info or perform malicious actions.  As I understand it, this means that the third-party library can access (and potentially abuse) all these same APIs, even if it does not declare the required permissions in its manifest.
How can I restrict/sandbox third party libraries in my app so they have access to the APIs needed for their stated purposes, and no more?

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  The OS doesn't know what parts of your app are a library and what parts are written by you.  When running an app there's no difference between a library class and one of your own.  If you don't trust a library, you shouldn't use it.